# Cannot upload mdb file through HTML form

Tags: php, file, ms-access, upload, forms

Not sure why it doesn't work entirely for mdb files, it doesn't even return any data.

I have the following HTML form:

```
if(!isset($_GET['action'])) {
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?page=mypage&action=upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="64000" type="hidden" />
        <label for="data-file">Please select file to upload:</label>
        <input id="data-file" type="file" size="20" name="data-file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" />
    </form>
    <?php
} else {
    switch($_GET['action']) {
        case 'upload':
            var_dump($_POST);
            var_dump($_FILES);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

When I select a mdb file and click on submit, it returns me two empty arrays:

```
'array(0) { } array(0) { }'
```

But if I select other files like excel file or image file, I get:

```
array(1) { ["submit"]=> string(6) "Upload" }
array(1) { ["data-file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(18) "testing.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(26) "C:\WINDOWS\Temp\php951.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(110533) } }
```

Does anyone have idea why the above is happening?

Also, I tried to delete most the data in my mdb file that I was trying to upload
to decrease the filesize to less than 1MB and uploaded again and it worked.
So I check my php.ini on the server but the upload_max_filesize is set to 64M
and my original mdb filesize is 14MB.

I don't understand why its not uploading nor returning any data not even errors.
This is frustrating.

Please help!

Comment: Maybe there are some restrictions on content-type of the uploaded files?

Comment: this might be relevant http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the server setting,

I had to change the settings in `php.ini`

Make sure

```
memory_limit >= post_max_size >= upload_max_filesize
```

In your `php.ini`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's `MAX_FILE_SIZE`.

> The MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden field (measured in bytes) must precede the
>   file input field, and its value is the maximum file size accepted by
>   PHP.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

So, `64000Byte / 1024 = 62,5 KB`

Try to delete the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` field.

Comment: Yes this could be one of the reasons but not in this case, thank you so much though.